# Visa ban for the UK. Does this also affect an application for a US spousal visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, us-citizens, immigration, marriage, student-visa

I was **banned** from the UK for ten years, for submitting a non-genuine bank statement while applying for a student visa (to the UK).

My ban will end in two more years. I am now a spouse of a US citizen.  I want to know if the UK ban will affect application for a US visa? As i am intending immigration into the US.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get a criminal charge (or possibly a conviction) over the forgery/fraud case? If so, your USA visa application may be hurt by foreign criminal records.

If not, there shouldn't be any impact. The USA visa application process does not depend on your UK visa status.

Comment: Except that most visa applications have a question similar to "have you ever been refused a visa?", and ask you to elaborate if the answer is 'yes'.

Comment: In the applicable form _I-130_ (http://www.uscis.gov/i-130) this is question 16: "Has your relative ever been under immigration proceedings?". If you look at http://travel.state.gov/content/visas/english/general/denials.html, the main concern would be "moral turpitude" (i.e. the potential immigrant has a track record of dishonest behaviour). Given the assumptions that its (a) a single case, (b) not related to the USA and (c) there was no real criminal intent, I believe that there wouldn't be good grounds against a waiver.

Comment: @freek Wiekmeijer    Question no.16 in this form.... Has your relative ever been under immigration proceedings? but I think immigration amounts to live permanently in a foreign country buh i was applied for temporary visa (study visa)

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer, how can someone engage in fraud without criminal intent?

Comment: Moreover, Question is whether immigration offense is like a conviction?

Comment: @mani42 With regards to the definition of "immigration" and whether the student visa application should be mentioned at all, I recommend a consult with a US-based immigratiom attorney. The whole situation makes your visa application slightly out of the ordinary. Given the high stakes of being able to live together wigh your spouse, ai would not go without the legal advise.

Comment: As for the conviction, you only have that if the UK immigrations office took your case to court. A decision by the immigrations office itself is not a court conviction.

Comment: @GayotFow With "criminal intent" I mean defrauding for financial gain. Obviously that kind of behavior would be a deal breaker for US immigration. if the whole case was merely about trying to get a student visa 8 years ago (perhaps at a young age), it seems like something you can get off the table if you have a proper attorney.